# Mapping through an array but not rendering Properly

Tags: javascript

The code below is showing the JSON data but it is not displaying it the way it should. I want my result `res.recipe.ingredient` to be displayed in an ordered list, starting from 1 to the end of the loop but the data is rendering all the output at number 1 and it is been separating with a comma. I am using pure javascript. 
[image]

```js
function showRecipe(food) {

    let output = '';

    let show = food.hits.forEach(function (res) {

      output += `
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>${res.recipe.label}</h3>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-block mb-4"> View Profile </a>
            <img class="img-fluid mb-2" src="${res.recipe.image}">
           <h4>${res.recipe.calories}</h4>
           <h3>Ingredient:</h3>
           <ul class="list-group">
           <li>${res.recipe.ingredients.map(text => text.text)} 
           </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
        ` 
    });  
    this.recipes.innerHTML = output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the below change, where we add an `li` tag to each element in the array and then using `join` method convert it back to a string.

from:

```
   <ul class="list-group">
       <li>${res.recipe.ingredients.map(text => text.text)} 
       </li>
   </ul>
```

To:

```
   <ul class="list-group">
       ${res.recipe.ingredients.map(text => `<li>${text.text}</li>`).join('')} 
   </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked but number one (1. ) on every loop is empty.

Comment: @toeyeen The array ingredients is having some elements with text as empty, kindly remove these values or use this alternate code `${res.recipe.ingredients.filter(item => item.text).map(text => `<li>${text.text}</li>`).join('')} ` where we will filter out all the empty text

Comment: The first solution actually worked, I had a <li></li> hanging somewhere, Thank you for your response, duly appreciated.